# jQuery Popup Tooltip ID on blocks

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip

I took the ready [jQuery Script for Tooltip](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/681/jQuery-and-CSS3-Simple-Tooltip.html) (I am not a Javascript Coder) to implent on my Site.

The Problem is that the Code only allows the Tooltip Hover if the Text is between the `<a></a>`. Putting it out will not show the effect. To format between `<a></a>` with DIV and is not the best way. How can i run the Javascript that the effect works also outside the `<a></a>`

The Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Tooltips
    $(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){
        tip = $(this).find('.tip');
        tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    }, function() {
        tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip        
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
        var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
        var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

        //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
        var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
        //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
        var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

        if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
            mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
        } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
            mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
        } 
        tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
    });
});

</script>
```

The CSS

```
.tip {
    color: #fff;
    background:#1d1d1d;
    display:none; /*--Hides by default--*/
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

The HTML

```
<p>Text<a class="tip_trigger" href="#">MouseOver<span class="tip">
<img src="image.jpg" />Show as MouseOver Effect</span></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a fast look on your code and everything seems to be fine. It's not the anchor tag that tell you what a tooltip is or is not but actually the following structure:

class='tip_trigger' > class='tip'.

You may have a div .tip_trigger and other tag inside of it with the .tip class and it should work.

So, taking your example, the problem is that you're using .tip_trigger inside of the "a" tag, but you can use it inside the "p" tag, like so:

```
<p class="tip_trigger"><a href="#">MouseOver<span class="tip">
<img src="image.jpg" />Show as MouseOver Effect</span>Text</a></p>
```

and it should work properly.

Comment: I want to show also some Content inside the Hover Effect. Thats why if i add any other tag it will not show it inside. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mBShz/3/

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you can use a `<span/>`.

Technically, it will accept any kind of element as long as you put the classname `tip_trigger` there.

```
<p>
    Text
    <span class="tip_trigger">MouseOver
        <span class="tip"><img src="image.jpg" />Show as MouseOver Effect</span>
    </span>
</p>​
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ5Pw/)

Comment: You are right its working but if i put DIV inside than it does not show the Effect. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mBShz/2/

Comment: @karabey, that's incorrect markup. Now, I realized that phrase I couldn't understand at all in your question was you asking to put a `<div>` inside `p > a`

Comment: Yes, while this is not possible how can i put it out of "a" tag and still show the Effect

Comment: @karabey, I got some time now. Did you manage to resolve your problems?